# Displaying a multi-table mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is going to be really hard to explain but I'll attempt to do my best without confusing you all. I have the following table design;

[image: Mysql Table]

Here is my mysqlFiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1363c/1

As you can see, the tables work fine and the query is displaying what shelter has what service but my issue comes when I attempt to display this information on my web. I'm currently using the following code;

```
<?php
    echo '<p>', "<strong>Shelter id</strong>: " . $query['shelter_id'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>', "<strong>Shelter name</strong>: " . $query['shelter_name'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>', "<strong>Street</strong>: " . $query['street'].'</p>';     
    echo '<p>', "<strong>City</strong>: " . $query['city'].'</p>';    
    echo '<p>', "<strong>Postcode</strong>: " . $query['postcode'].'</p>';  
    echo '<p>', "<strong>Contact Number</strong>: " . $query['phone_number'].'</p>';  
    echo '<p>', "<strong>Location</strong> :  " . $query['location_name'].'</p>'; 
?>
```

but with the query I'm using, Its not going going to dupe all the information into one row it is, its going to create multiple row's for the service_name, I think.

Is it possible for me to create a query that will return all service's the shelter can do on one row?

Edit: Will i have to do 2 separate query's? One to get the generic shelter information and then another query to return the services into an array and then just run through them on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using `GROUP_CONCAT`? What it does is it combines the values into comma separated value. And you can later use `Explode()` in `PHP`.

```
SELECT  shelter_name, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(services.service_name)  service_name
FROM    shelter
        INNER JOIN shelter_service 
          ON shelter.shelter_id= shelter_service.shelter_id
        INNER JOIN services 
          ON shelter_service.service_id = services.service_id
GROUP   BY shelter.shelter_id, shelter_name
ORDER   BY shelter_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1363c/4)

Comment: Yet again, JW, you come in the save the day! That query appears to return the information perfectly. I've not used the "Explode()" method before, how exactly does it work?

Comment: Awesome, got the the query working for returning all the elements needed. Having some trouble displaying the information though. I've used "var_dump" and it shows that the array contains the correct information but how do I then go out display it in a way the user can see? I took a guess at;

echo '<p>', "<strong>Services</strong> :  " . explode( ',', $query['service_name'] ).'</p>';

Comment: Excellent! Did a foreach loop on the array and then displayed each element and now we have this!

http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0862025/CodeIgniter_temp/index.php/user_page/viewShelterDetails/1

Possibly the worst code ever but horray!

Comment: JW, can the GROUP_CONCAT, contain two extractable data types? Or would I have to create two GROUP_CONCATS?

Comment: Darn, I need to return more than just the animal_name. Is it going to be a very dumb idea to simple use more than 1 Group_concat?

Answer (score 1):

1. GROUP_CONCAT() use only if you have a limited number of rows (10-100), if the data is larger will slow your query a lot.
2. 2 queries (one for types one for data)
3. keep this query and modify the result (my favorite way).
   On server or JS loop trough your data and restructure it (add 1 extra dimension)

```js
var new_data = {};
for(var i in data)//data is your $query
{
  var row = data[i];
  //create another layer of the array (make it in 2 dimensions)
  if (typeof(new_data[row['Service_name']) == 'undefined)
     new_data['Service_name'] = [];
   //add only this kind of type data
     new_data['Service_name'].push(data);
 }
//now you can remove the data and use new_data
```

.4. Make sure the query is primarly sorted by Service name, and when you loop at display (echo) you show the current service name.

```
$current_name = '';
for(...)
 //if we passed to a new service in the loop
if ($query['service_name'] != $current_name) {
   echo '<h3>'.$query['service_name'].'</h3>;//display the new service
    $current_name = $query['service_name'];
}
```